# Format NSDecimalNumber to currency by country code without loss of precision

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter, nsdecimalnumber, currency-formatting

So right now I have the following code:

```objc
- (NSString*)convertToLocalCurrencyFormat:(NSDecimalNumber*)result {
  NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
  formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
  formatter.currencyCode = self.comparisonCurrency;
  formatter.usesSignificantDigits = YES;
  return [formatter stringFromNumber:result];
}
```

When I pass in an `NSDecimalNumber*` containing `678071967196719797153475347466.94627863`, it gets formatted to `¥678,072,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000` (with the `currencyCode` set to `JPY`). If I leave out the `formatter.usesSignificantDigits = YES` line, then it gets formatted to `¥678,071,967,196,719,797,153,475,347,467`, closer, but still dropping the decimal and following values.

However, when I pass in `6780.0416000000012517376`, it's formatted *correctly* to `¥6,780.04` with the significant digits line. It gets formatted to `¥6,780` without the significant digits line.

I know that NSNumberFormatter can take in any NSNumber as a parameter, but can only deal with values as precise as doubles, leaving NSDecimalNumber with no errors and incorrect results.

How can I format NSDecimalNumbers with currency codes without loss of precision?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the minimum fraction digits instead:

```
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2;
```

HTH